# Retain MAX value of Aerospike CDT List

Tags: scala, aerospike

### Context

Consider having a stream of tuples `(string, timestamp)`, with the goal of having a bin containing a `Map` of the **minimal** timestamp received for each string.
Another constraint is that the update for this Map will be atomic.

For this input example:

```
("a", 1)
("b", 2)
("a", 3)
```

the expected output: `Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)` without the maximal timestamp `3`.

The current implementation I chose is using CDT of list to hold the timestamps, so my result is `Map("a" -> ArrayList(1), "b" -> ArrayList(2))` as follows:

```
private val boundedAndOrderedListPolicy = new ListPolicy(ListOrder.ORDERED, ListWriteFlags.INSERT_BOUNDED)

private def bundleContext(str: String) =
      CTX.mapKeyCreate(Value.get(str), MapOrder.UNORDERED)

private def buildInitTimestampOp(tuple: (String, Long)): List[Operation] = {
      // having these two ops together assure that the size of the list is always 1
      val str = tuple._1
      val timestamp = tuple._2
      val bundleCtx: CTX = bundleContext(str)
      List(
        ListOperation.append(boundedAndOrderedListPolicy, initBin, Value.get(timestamp), bundleCtx),
        ListOperation.removeByRankRange(initBin, 1, ListReturnType.NONE, bundleCtx), // keep the first element of the order list - earliest time
      )
    }
```

This works as expected. However, if you have a better way to achieve this without the list and in an atomic manner - I would love to hear it.

### My question

What does not work for me is retaining the **max timestamp** received for each input str. For the example above, the desired result should be `Map("a" -> ArrayList(3), "b" -> ArrayList(2))`. My implementation attempt is:

```
private def buildLastSeenTimestampOp(tuple: (String, Long)): List[Operation] = {
      // having these two ops together assure that the size of the list is always 1
      val str = tuple._1
      val timestamp = tuple._2
      val bundleCtx: CTX = bundleContext(str)
      List(
        ListOperation.append(boundedAndOrderedListPolicy, lastSeenBin, Value.get(timestamp), bundleCtx),
        ListOperation.removeByRankRange(lastSeenBin, 1, ListReturnType.NONE | ListReturnType.REVERSE_RANK, bundleCtx), // keep the last element of the ordered list - last time
      )
    }
```

Any idea why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 6):

So, i've solved it:

```
private def buildLastSeenTimestampOp(tuple: (String, Long)): List[Operation] = {
      // having these two ops together assure that the size of the list is always 1
      val str = tuple._1
      val timestamp = tuple._2
      val bundleCtx: CTX = bundleContext(str)
      List(
        ListOperation.append(boundedAndOrderedListPolicy, lastSeenBin, Value.get(command.timestamp.getMillis), bundleCtx),
        ListOperation.removeByRankRange(lastSeenBin, -1, ListReturnType.NONE | ListReturnType.INVERTED, bundleCtx), // keep the last element of the ordered list - last time
      )
    }
```

When dealing with Rank/Index (removeByIndexRange for indexes) in ascending order **-1 represent the max Rank/Index**.

Using the `ListReturnType.INVERTED` is retaining the range (or element in this case) that is selected by initial `rank`/`index` until `count` - by deleting all elements of the list that aren't in the selected range.